# Cannot connect to Kubernetes cluster with kubectl and liveness probe fails

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-autodevops

### Update

We commented out the django migration and collectstatic from our Dockerfile and we managed to make a new deployment (the liveness/readinnes probe passed). We thought it would be something related to one of them, but then we returned with both `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py collecstatic` and everything kept working. So, the deploys are working but we don't know why they stopped working.

**But we still cannot connect to the healthy/running pods using `kubectl`**. We are still receiving timeout errors. Even from Gitlab interface.

---

We have an application running on a Kubernetes cluster managed by the [Gitlab AutoDevops](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/). A few days ago, for some reason unknown, we are not able to connect to our Pods using `kubectl` anymore. We receive `Error from server: error dialing backend: dial timeout, backstop`.  To connect to the pod we use `kubectl -n <namespace> exec -it <pod> -- bash`

Additionally, at the same time, our deploys started to fail due to **liveness** and **readiness** probe failure. Checking on GKE, we see the messages:

- `Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.59.1.234:5000/": dial tcp 10.59.1.232:5000: connect: connection refused`
- `Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.59.1.234:5000/": dial tcp 10.59.1.232:5000: connect: connection refused`

I've tried to increase the value of `initialDelaySeconds` - Helm variable to control the Probe - but without success. There is a timeout error after 5min (`Error: release review-fix-run-pi-xrsd0t failed, and has been uninstalled due to atomic being set: timed out waiting for the condition`)

The application is still up and running, but we can't make new deploys or access the pods.

Below there is the output from the command `kubectl -n <namespace> describe pod <pod>` which was executed during the pipeline. After a few minutes, the pipeline failed.

```
IP:           10.59.1.234
IPs:
  IP:           10.59.1.234

Port:           5000/TCP
Host Port:      0/TCP
State:          Running

Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  75s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned daeb5798-review-fix-run-pi-xrsd0t/review-fix-run-pi-xrsd0t-6c975b9f4d-wgc4r to gke-os-us-central1-default-pool-da55e92e-8ssdxx
  Normal   Pulling    55s               kubelet            Pulling image "registry.gitlab.com/fix-run-pipeline:6a43a82369e87eee4ad86023694167aef6886451"
  Normal   Pulled     53s               kubelet            Successfully pulled image "registry.gitlab.com/fix-run-pipeline:6a43a82369e87eee4ad86023694167aef6886451" in 2.819782241s
  Normal   Created    51s               kubelet            Created container auto-deploy-app
  Normal   Started    49s               kubelet            Started container auto-deploy-app
  Warning  Unhealthy  5s (x4 over 35s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.59.1.234:5000/readiness/": dial tcp 10.59.1.234:5000: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  5s (x3 over 25s)  kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.59.1.234:5000/healthz/": dial tcp 10.59.1.234:5000: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Killing    5s                kubelet            Container auto-deploy-app failed liveness probe, will be restarted
```

Something tells me that this issue is related to our cluster internal network. But I don't know where to go from here.

We also noticed some warnings about pods with unready status:
[image]

Any tips on how to solve or investigate this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `...dial tcp 10.59.1.234:5000: connect: connection refused` - have you checked the pod log to ensure the server which listen to port 5000 is up & running?

Comment: I am taking a wild guess here, I guess your application has some error cause it didn't listen to port 5000.
Remove `Liveness`  and `Readiness` from YAML file, so the cluster don't kill the pod, then you can connect the pod by command `kubectl -n <namespace> exec -it <pod> -- bash`

Comment: Did you already determine which pod is unhealthy/having issues? Can you check or share the logs. You can use this filter on Logs Explorer to check.  (resource.type="k8s_container"   
resource.labels.pod_name=POD_NAME)

Comment: @gohm'c I've just created a new git branch from the main branch, which currently running. The pipeline also failed due to liveness/readiness probe failure

Comment: @yip102011 I've tried to remove the `Liveness` and `Readiness` from the pipeline, but as we use the Gitlab AutoDevops the Helm still uses its default value for the health check.
What I did was update `.gitlab/auto-deploy-values.yaml` file and set both `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` to  `{}`.

Any tips on how to disable the liveness and readiness step?

Helm values reference: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image/-/tree/master/assets/auto-deploy-app

Comment: Can you provide your values file?